# Why LSTM predicts the same value for all test cases?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a regression task and time series data. For each observation I need to predict one outcome value. My data is a series of images. I have hand-crafted 32 features from my images. Images have 10 channels. My data has 4D shape: (observations, time steps, channels, features), e.g. (3348, 121, 10, 32). After normalisation one channel for one observation looks like this:

`matplotlib.pyplot.matshow(normalized[170,:,0,:].transpose())`

[image: one observation after normalization]

The figure shows 121 time steps (x-axis) and each time step has features on rows (32). The intensity of feature value is shown in colors. So there seems to be something happening in time.

**Question 1: How to apply RNN in such a task?**

Could I somehow use CNN to extract information from my 3rd and 4th axis of my data (as shown in figure above)?

**A proposed solution (and troubles ahead):**

I have flattened the data into 3D. I think I have sadly degenerated information for the learner, but at least this (almost) works:

```
m,n = xtrain4d.shape[:2]
xtrain3d = xtrain4d.reshape(m,n,-1)
```

Shape is now: (3348, 121, 320). Target ytrain.shape is (3348,).

Here's my LSTM:

```
def LSTMrecurrentNN(shape1, shape2):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(shape1, shape2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    
    return model

model = LSTMrecurrentNN(xtrain3d.shape[1], xtrain3d.shape[2])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_12"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_11 (LSTM)               (None, 121, 128)          229888    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 121, 128)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 121, 64)           8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 121, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 121, 16)           1040      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, 121, 16)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 121, 1)            17        
=================================================================
Total params: 239,201
Trainable params: 239,201
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Running the model:

```
epochs = 20
batchsize=128 
learningrate=0.001 
epsilon=0.1

# monitor validation progress:
early = EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss", mode = "min", patience = 10)
callbacks_list = [early]

# compile:
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',
              optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learningrate, epsilon = epsilon),
              metrics = ['mse'])

# and train the model
history = model.fit(xtrain3d, ytrain,
    epochs=epochs,  batch_size=batchsize, verbose=0,
    validation_split = 0.20,
    callbacks = callbacks_list)

# predict:
test_predictions = model.predict(Xtest)
```

Training and validation performance looks ok:

[image: training and validation loss in epochs]

But on the test set the model predicts one value for all observations! The figure below shows how for 10 observations in the test set the model predicts already in the early time steps a value of 3267 that is close to the mean of target y.

[image: predictions for each time step for 10 observations in the test set]

Statistics tell the same:

```
scipy.stats.describe(test_predictions[:,-1,0])
```

```
DescribeResult(nobs=1544, minmax=(3267.813, 3267.813), 
mean=3267.8127, variance=5.964328e-08, skewness=1.0, kurtosis=-2.0)
```

For target y:

```
scipy.stats.describe(ytest)
```

```
DescribeResult(nobs=1544, minmax=(0.0, 8000.0), 
mean=3312.1081606217617, 
variance=1381985.8476585718, skewness=0.2847730511366937, kurtosis=0.20894280037919222)
```

**Question 2: Why the model predicts the same value for all?**

Any hints, how to check LSTM behaviour (states)? I would like to know how far back it "remembers".

Comment: Was Xtest normalized using the same transformations as Xtrain?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the data with similar matshow-plots at all stages (raw, normalised, reshaped to 3D).